# How to make a React web app an app-like website like Amazon or Flipkart?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web, user-experience, mobile-website

I have a React web app, and I want to make a mobile version of it with a different user experience just like Amazon. I want to know what they have used to achieve an app-like website?

Comment: Amazon serves content based on device from which user makes request.

Comment: So I just have to make different stylesheets for different devices? and serve them depending on what devices trying to load?

Comment: That could be one of solution,
Note that, you might also need to change layout structure as well,
depending upon design of your desktop app. Is desktop design is designed keeping responsiveness in mind? then you might need less effort.

Comment: The desktop version is already responsive, but the thing is I would like to introduce different UX in mobile only, like CTA buttons or navigation, which will be completely different in mobile. Do I also have to serve JS files differently?

Comment: You can show and hide CTA button based on CSS media queries.It is OK to not to serve related JS differently for such small difference.

If you are planning to update too many things, ovoid this methodology which will result in code bloat for desktop site.

Answer (score 0):

There are many component libraries available for ReactJS. Give a try to [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/), it’s used by Netflix, Amazon and other great organizations.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, I am having my custom style guide for my project. And, I want a different UX in mobile web, how do I achieve that? Is it possible only via CSS?

Comment: You might need to override semantic ui library styles for mobile devices using 'media queries'.

Comment: Yes, but that is when I want to have different style for my components. I want to have different components in mobile only, e.g. Amazon and Flipkart, how are they achieving app-like website?

Comment: For different components in Mobile, have a common selector to check if request is from mobile browser or desktop. Based on that, load your components. For app-like websites, read up on progressive web apps.